# segmentation fault in C memcpy

Tags: c

I have a basic problem using memcpy and don't understand where the problem is. I show below the relevant parts of the code. The code seg. faults in the last right iteration of the loop. Why can't I index in to an memory area that is reserved?

Thank you in advance.

```
mystr->data = malloc(2048);

unsigned char buf[8500];
for (i=0;i<32;i++){
    offset = i*256;
    memcpy(&mystr->data[64*i],&buf[8+offset],64);
}
```

Comment: `buf` isn't initialized?

Comment: what's the type of `mystr->data`?

Comment: @CoolGuy It will not segfault because of the crap contained in `buf`.

Comment: Hi Ingo, thank you for pointing this out - data was declared as: unsigned long long *data; Once this was corrected to unsigned char - the set fault disappeared.

Comment: Reading an uninitialised variable provokes undefined behaviour: Anything can happen! So just do a `unsigned char buf[8500] = {0};` and re-test.

Comment: I think @IngoLeonhardt is probably onto the issue.  If the type of `*mystr->data` is larger than one byte then `mystr->data[64*i]` will access past the end of the allocated block before `i` reaches 32.

Comment: yeah, if `mystr->data` is anything other than a `char *` the destination will fall off the ubuffer

Comment: OK i will post my suspicition which has been proved as an answer

Comment: @alk AFAIK, `buf` will have 8500 values, each between 0 and  255, so why it would cause a segfault?

Comment: I did not say is necessarily needs to cause a segmentation violation. But it could, for the reason mentioned. UB is an ugly beast.

Comment: @alk, the behavior is not "undefined" in the standard's sense of that term.  Prior to initialization, each element of `buf` has an *indeterminate value*, which means either an *unspecified value* or a trap representation.  That can produce undefined behavior only in the trap representation case, but even then, not when accessed via a variable of type [`unsigned`] `char`.  (C99 6.7.8/10, 3.17.2, 3.17.3, 6.2.6.1/3).  It is in any case unlikely that type `unsigned char` affords any trap representations in the OP's environment.

Comment: ... where "unlikely" is an overstatement: it follows from C99:6.2.6.2/1 that type `unsigned char` does not afford any trap representations.

Comment: Not sure why this question was down voted - even though I realise that it is a silly mistake of mine. I did spend quite some time hunting this bug though. Although, this discussion did help me fix the problem. Thanks to all for your help. Cheers!

Comment: Probably because it's more or less incomplete, as it does not give all info for all players involved. That typically is the type of `mystr->data`.

Answer (score 2):

From the comments it'cs clear that my suspicion was right:

if `sizeof( *mystr->data ) > 1` (because e.g. it's `unsigned long long *data;`) then you run beyond the end of the buffer because the offsets calculated by expressions like `&mystr->data[64*i]` are relative to the type, here it is `mystr->data` + `64*i*sizeof(*mystr->data) bytes` which was up to 64*31*8 in your code.

You could either change the type, as you have done, or change the offsets (to `&mystr->data[8*i]` in your case) depending on what what seems 'right' semantically in your context

Comment: ... or you could force the code to count in bytes by doing: `memcpy(&((char*) (mystr->data))[64*i],&buf[8+offset],64);`